# Predicate natural deduction: Prove (∀x R(x,x)) => ∀x∃y R(x,y)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Prove that if the relation R is reflexive, it is also serial:

$ \forall x \space R(x,x) \vdash \forall x \exists y \space R(x,y)$

I've tried this so far but can't think of anything further:

$1. \space \forall x R(x,x) \space\space\space\space\space premise \\ 2. \space R(x0,x0) \space\space\space\space\space \forall x-elimination, \space from \space line \space 1 \\3. \space ... $

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please give a little more clarification on your question, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Is $y=x$ valid?

Comment: In words: show that if R is reflexive, it is also serial.
Since y and x is from the same set, it can be that y = x.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines in your question.  In particular, define your terms clearly. What do you mean by "natural deduction proof"? Are you using first-order predicate calculus or something else? You probably should tell us your axioms and rules of deduction: they vary between logical systems. Without those it is difficult to help you.

Comment: *natural deduction* is a precise term [in formal logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction).  However, I believe that there are several different natural deduction systems, so please specify which you are using, and what you have tried.  As it stands I thinkt his should be closed as missing context.

Comment: That second edit wasn't an improvement: what do you mean by 2. $x_0$ and $\forall x e, 1$ in 3.?

Comment: It's just the way of applying the natural deduction rules of predicate logic following a book (Logic in Computer Science by Michael Huth and Mark Ryan). ∀xe,1 says that we applied the ∀x-elimination of line 1.

Comment: In that case, maybe change $\forall xe, 1$ to something more descriptive (e.g., $\forall x$-elimination from line 1) to be independent from one particular book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

1. $\forall x R(x,x)$,

apply $\forall$-elimination:

2. $R(x_0, x_0)$

Then $\exists$-introduction. (The trick is to only use the second $x_0$: we're starting from $R(x_0, x_0)$ which is equal to $R(x_0,t) [t := x_0]$.)

3. $\exists y R(x_0,y)$

Finally apply $\forall$-introduction:

4. $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)$.

Comment: Alright, I was wondering if you could do that (only use the ∃-introduction on the second x0) but was unsure about it. But it seems it is valid then. Couldn't think of any other way. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I guessed, but next time: add that kind of information directly to the question! It will help people help you.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first time asking a question in a stackexchange.

Comment: No worries, the question has become much better now :-) and you'll get the hang of asking questions here.